# ¿Como evito que se siga escribiendo en un textbox en c#?

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero realizar es que cuando llegue al limite de 10 caracteres que el usuario escribió en mi pequeño sistema me marque error y ya no escriba mas, pero lo que pasa es que solo marca el error pero cada vez que ingreso un nuevo numero lo recibe y lo pone en el textbox

Este es el código de restricción y se encuentra en el textbox.

```
private void clave_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (clave.Text.Length>10) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asignar a 10 la propiedad máx length de tu TextBox no hay porqué manipular los eventos Keypress o TextChange para ese fin

`textBox1.MaxLength = 10;`

Answer (score 3):

Si es un TextBox de asp.Net, puedes usar la propiedad MaxLength y le indicas la cantidad de caracteres que se limitarán, algo como así:

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: En asp no hay MessageBox

Comment: en este caso es asp.Net, gracias David por la aclaración.

Comment: en asp.net tampoco ;)  jeje, lo que quiero decir es que en la pregunta se usa un MessageBox por lo tanto debe ser winforms :)

Comment: jaja OK, entendido. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`TextChanged` no es el mejor evento para tu proposito, es mejor que utilices [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) y uses `Handle=true` para controlar el evento de pulsación.

Pero si tu propósito es limitar el máximo de caracteres en un TextBox también tienes la propiedad [MaxLenght](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) que indica el máximo de caracteres que puede contener.

Saludos,